# Where and when will someone on Earth be standing with the floor parallel to the Ecliptic plane?

Tags: orbit, earth, ecliptic

I have been trying to figure this out and I think the answer might be - once per day for anyone living on the Tropic of Cancer or Capricorn. Is that right? To be clear - I want to know where on Earth and when/how often a person standing upright will be standing with the floor parallel to the ecliptic plane? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think it's the Arctic and Antarctic Circles once a sidereal day at any given longitude, but if you want to doublecheck, but you can use planetarium program like Stellarium. If the entire ecliptic is at the horizon, you're parallel to it.

Comment: What Barry said. The ecliptic will be parallel to the floor & horizon planes when a pole of the ecliptic is overhead (at the zenith). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_pole

Comment: @WillT The title and body of the post ask two different questions. Which question do you want answered? Title: person parallel to ecliptic plane. Body: floor parallel to ecliptic plane, so person is perpendicular to the ecliptic.

Comment: edited Question. Yes I mean with Floor parallel